# How can I format my text file to make it not repeat the same line over and over?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to write a text file using C++ ,but it keeps repeating the line. Is there a certain way to format to make it only have the line once and not 10 times? This is my code and when I try to make it write the definition for the keyword it writes the whole thing multiple times.

```
int main() {
    //Count number of keywords
    //Enter keywords
    std::string keywords[] = {"Asm","Auto","Bool","Break","Case","Catch",
        "Char","Class","Const","Const_cast","Continue","Default","Delete","Do","Double"
        ,"Dynamic_cast","else","enum","explicit","export","extern","false","float",
        "For","Friend","Goto","If","Inline","Int","Long","Mutable","Namespace","New","Operator","Private","Protected","Public","Register"
        ,"Reinterpret_cast","Return","Short","Signed","Sizeof","Static","Static_cast","Struct",
        "Switch","Template","This","Throw","True","Try","Typedef","Typeid",
        "Typename","Union","Unsigned","Using","Virtual","Void","Volatile","Wchar_t","While"};
    //Reserved keywords
    std::string reserved[] = {"And","And_eq","Bitand","Bitor","Compl","Not","Not_eq","Or_eq","Xor","Xor_eq"};
    //output
    std::ofstream obj_file_handle;
    //input
    std::ifstream obj_file_handle2;
    obj_file_handle2.open("Input or Output.txt");
    obj_file_handle.open("C++Refernce_upgraded.txt");

    //Count the keywords
    std::string Line2;
    int ReservedNum = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> found_reservedWord;
    int KeywordNum = 0;
    std::vector<std::string> found_keyword;
    while (std::getline(obj_file_handle2, Line2))
    {
        for (std::string keyword : keywords) {
            if (Line2.find(keyword) != std::string::npos)
                KeywordNum++;
            found_keyword.push_back(Line2);
        }
        //Count the Reserved Keywords
        for (std::string reserved_word : reserved) {
            if (Line2.find(reserved_word) != std::string::npos) {
                ReservedNum++;
                found_reservedWord.push_back(Line2);
            }
        }
    }
        //Definitions
        obj_file_handle << "C++ Keywords defined =  " << KeywordNum << std::endl;
        for (std::string definition : found_keyword) {
            obj_file_handle << definition << std::endl;
        }
        obj_file_handle << "C++ Reserved Keywords defined =  " << ReservedNum << std::endl;
        for (std::string definition : found_reservedWord) {
            obj_file_handle << definition << std::endl;

        }

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: You should remove the loop.

Comment: You should remove the `ios::app` flag, so it is not appending data all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your code is doing what you told it to do, instead of what you actually wanted. When are these computers going to become mind readers? I know, right!

```
1 Read a line of text.
2 for each keyword, 
    add the whole line of text to the "found list"
    (whether it is found or not)
3 output the "found list"
```

It's doing what you asked it to do. Duplicate the whole line, X times, where X is the count of items in those two arrays of keywords and reserved words.